# Is there a way to add a sub class to a reflected flask-sqlalchemy table

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a mssql database that I am reflecting.  Is there a way to add a custom Model class to this kind of database?

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(db.engine, reflect=True)
Users = Base.classes.Users
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me with my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`automap_base`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.automap_base) takes `declarative_base` as an argument, or creates one if not provided.

Hence you can create one of your own and provide.
[`declarative_base`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.declarative_base) does take an argument `cls` which you can use to achieve exactly what you need.

```
class MyBase(...):
   ...

Base = automap_base(declarative_base(cls=MyBase))
```